# Product attibutes are showing have same values

Tags: magento2

I am trying to get product attributes on cart page by using the following code, but it gives attribute values of previous product if it has no value (empty)

```
<?php   $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
    $_product = $objectManager->get('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($product->getId()); 

echo $product->getShortDescription();

?>
```

Answer (score 4):

Using the object manager directly is wrong but to solve your problem quickly ... use `$objectManager->create` instead of `$objectManager->get`

Comment: Thanks!  yes its working but if it is wrong then how can i get attributes using some other way?

Comment: @Marius, It's working for me on grouped product detail page.

Answer (score 0):

In cart page.If you have **Cart item object then using**  Then you can description value by below code:

> ```
> echo $_item->getProduct()->getResource()->getAttribute('description');
> ```

$_item->getProduct() give u product object then using resource model `$_item->getProduct()->getResource()`, you can get description field value.